# Is there a way to catch a HTTP request to a non existing custom handler for Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

I'm new to Razor Pages and I have an issue with handler methods. Say, I call a page with a custom handler, but have forgotten to implement this particular handler, the default POST or GET handlers are used. Is there a way to change that or catch that?

Let's say I make an HTTP-GET request to a page using

```
/xyz?handler=dostuff
```

but havn't got the handler *OnGetDoStuff*, the default handler *OnGet* with be executed.

```
public class XyzModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    // missing handler public void OnGetDoStuff(){...}
}
```

I understand that the handler is just a parameter in the GET request, so I could check the request url in every default method to see if a custom handler was handed over. But I would like something like an 404. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, as I haven't tried this myself. However, given that the handler is passed as a query string param, it's possible the Razor Page will fallback to the default handler for the HTTP method. If that is the case, then you should be able to look for the handler in `Request.Query` and do whatever you want in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [global filter](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters) for this.

As Chris Pratt says in his comment, the framework will fall back to executing the default `OnGet` handler if no matching named handler exists. You can detect this within an overridden `OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync` method in a class that implements `IAsyncPageFilter`. Rough and ready, but something along the following lines will do:

```
public class CustomPageFilter : IAsyncPageFilter
{
    public async Task OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
    {
        var handler = context.HttpContext.Request.Query["handler"];
        if (handler.Count > 0)
        {
            var handlerMethodName = handler.ToArray()[0].ToLower();
            var method = context.HandlerMethod.MethodInfo.Name.ToLower();
            if (!method.EndsWith(handlerMethodName))
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            }
        }
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

The `OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync` method runs after the handler method has been selected. The simple test here checks to see if the selected method name ends with the value passed to the `handler` query string value. If it doesn't, the handler method is missing.

As the article I linked to shows, you configure the global filter in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new CustomPageFilter());
})
```